# What could cause a group of machines to fail loading secure web pages only when assigned certain IP addresses?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ip, https, internet

I have about 20 cloned machines running Windows XP Pro SP3.

Three of the computers are experiencing an issue where clicking the 'Proceed to checkout' button from the amazon.com shopping cart causes the browser to time out while trying to load the next page (This is going from http https).

All of the other machines behave normally on that site.

The page on affected computers displays “waiting for https://www.amazon.com/gp/cart/[the rest of the url]...” on the status bar.
On ‘healthy’ systems, the page completes loading nearly instantly.

The odd thing is, when the issue happens, it happens in IE and Firefox and Chrome in exactly the same way as described above.  Clearing cache/cookies does nothing to resolve the issue.

On affected machines, the issue happens in the limited User profile, the Administrator profile, and even happens on newly created test profiles.

As the computers are physically identical and the software was cloned to each one, I looked at the differences between them.

TEST-006 (not affected by issue) has an assigned IP of 192.168.1.126.

TEST-030 (affected by issue) has an assigned IP of 192.168.1.27.

When I assigned 192.168.1.126 to TEST-030, the computer was no longer affected by the issue.

When I assigned 192.168.1.27 to TEST-006, the computer was affected by the issue.

Assigning 192.168.1.27 to PROD-012 (Different computer type with a different image) did NOT cause the issue on that computer. Plugging one of the TEST computers assigned with 192.168.1.27 into the same port PROD-012 used had no effect.  The TEST computer was still affected.

Setting the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 didn't affect the issue one way or another.

This is driving me nuts, what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: IP address conflict, maybe?

Comment: @HopelessN00b It doesn't seem that way.  When I removed the computer with the IP assigned to it from the network, I was unable to ping the IP.

Comment: What's the net mask on the computers? 255.255.255.0 or something else? Is the network segmented where the computers are (connected to different switches/routers)?

Comment: @Alfabravo It's a /21 network.  There are different switches, but I believe all of these computers connect through the same one.

Comment: Check if there's no problem with infrastructure. Networking hardware in between, their config settings, their routing tables, etc.